# How to exit an if statement once the condition is met

Tags: javascript

I have the "resize" event on the window object. Inside, there is an if statement that is monitoring the window.innerWidth. As soon as the if statement is satisfied, I want to exit the if statement and no longer execute the code inside. This should result in only one console.log output, even as the viewport continues to shrink. Below is my code:

`window.addEventListener('resize', () => { if (window.innerWidth < 640) {console.log(window.innerWidth)} })`

See code above to see

Comment: There is no more code inside your if statement. It seems that you want to remove the listener instead of exiting the if statement

Answer (score 4):

See the [documentation for `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Note that among the `options` is:

> once Optional
>
> A boolean value indicating that the listener should be invoked at most once after being added. If true, the listener would be automatically removed when invoked. If not specified, defaults to false.

Thus:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 640) {
        console.log(window.innerWidth)
    }
}, {
    once: true
});
```